# Best way to display users by location

Tags: charts

I'm trying to find out which is the best way to display amount of users by location. 
In my application, you can create locations and sub-locations without limit. Then, you can assign users to each location. The thing here is that you can assign users in every level of your tree. For example, if you have Argentina > Buenos Aires, you can add users to Argentina and even to Buenos Aires.

Now, I need to represent in a chart how many users you have in each location, so I thought that a Pie could be a good idea in order to understand the percentage that each location has about the amount of users. The challenge is that you have a tree of locations, and you can assign users in every level.

I tried creating a graph in Highcharts but I think it's not too representative.
If you take a look, South Park has 5 users and Brasil 40. The size of the piece of South Park it's similar to Brasil because of the hierarchy drawn, and that's not intuitive in a first sight.

Here's my example: http://jsfiddle.net/94y7z5ro/5/

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about making the chart interactive, i.e. first you show all entry levels indicating that they are clickable. And all of the diameter of all 3 circles now.

Once you click on Argentina, it shrinks adding a new slice of a circle, now divided into Cordoba and Buenos Aires, while Brasil remains the same size. Of course Cordoba and Buenos Aires show they are expandable. Now, clicking on Buenos Aires makes a new slice appear, divided respectively.

See the picture below:
[image]

Comment: I think this approach is not possible with Highcharts because you can't make a piece of the chart that has multiple levels of the chart. I can't find out how to do that with this plugin :(

Comment: Try donut chart with 3 circles already, presenting all levels on each circle (and no border between the circles). Then, upon clicking on certain part, the circle (together with an outer circle) gets split to a lower level, and so on. I'm not familiar with highcharts but after a glimpse I'm sure a lot can be done to suit your needs (worst case scenario - several charts stacked above each other, playing with opacity, Z-index, etc).